# Fedex Api Rate Calculator

Tags: fedex

Parameters to be passed  to  the Fedex API .
New Fedex APi rate calculator not working  getting Authentiction  error
1000 "Authentication Failed" error

Comment: REST API users: if this happens to you, then in all likelihood you aren't correctly getting a token (step 1) or passing the token  (step 2).  See an example of how to do that in this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74710482/curl-and-fedex-api-responding-with-gibberish-in-php

Answer (score 2):

First off, your question is not very descriptive, but the error you are getting is because either your developer key or your password are incorrect.

If you have not already done so, I suggest you go to https://www.fedex.com/wpor/web/jsp/drclinks.jsp?links=wss/develop.html. Towards the bottom of that page there is a link that says "Obtain Developer Test Key". From there, just fill out the form and FedEx should send you your credentials along with a server URL to use.

The credentials you will need are a Developer Key, Account Number, Meter Number, and Password. The Developer key will be an alpha-numeric string containing 16 characters. The Account Number  and meter number will each consist only of numbers and each consists of 9 characters. The password will be an alpha-numeric string consisting of 25 characters.